# Asp.Net WebApi, REST controller and byte array deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, deserialization

i have implemented a controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("DefaultAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Person obj){
}
```

Person is this class:

```
public class Person
{
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public byte[] ImageStream { get; set; }
}
```

At client side i make this call to post new Person:

```
var person={
            "Name":"Test",
            "ImageStream":"AQID"
}

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/person",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(person),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result); //log to the console to see whether it worked
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
            }
});
```

The problem is that i receive the Person obj with ImageStream set as null.

To test if ImageStream string that i use is correct i tried this:

```
Person p=new Person();
p.Name="Test";
p.ImageStream=new byte[]{1,2,3};
String json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Javascript code you are not passing a byte array to your C# method, you're passing a string.  They are not the same thing.  If you want to pass a byte array, it needs to be an actual array of numbers whose values are between 0 and 255.

Try it like this:

```
var person = {
    "Name": "Test",
    "ImageStream": [65,81,73,68]
}
```

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't works. It works only sometimes, my solutions too, works only sometimes and i don't understand why.